# Remote.it and openVPN together

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, remote-access, openvpn

So this is a classic question that I’ve seen many times before...

I’m trying to connect to my home network when not at home using a raspberry pi.

I’m well aware that the way to go with this is to use a vpn server such as OpenVPN.

However, in order to connect to the vpn I would need to forward a port on my router... which I can’t do.

I’ve found remote.it which allows remote connection to a computer (pi) without port forwarding.

What I would like to know is how would I set about using the 2 together, I.e. connecting to remote.it which in turn connects me to my vpn server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ZeroTier(https://www.zerotier.com/). It haves its own linux client , and you can connect to as many networks as you would like.
You can also configure IP address from the website.
There is also an Android an IOS app that is really simple to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to be finding this question just now, but in case it's still useful to you or to anyone else, here's what you need to do:

- Install remote.it
- Set-up a remote.it connection to use the protocol (TCP/UDP) and port required by the VPN application
- Make a remote.it connection/adding the service to your network (remoteit - Desktop application UI terminology)
- Use this connection info (URL/port or localhost:port) with the VPN client
- Send an e-mail to support@remote.it if you need help